# Change CALayer color in sync with UIView tintColor when a UIViewController presents a popover

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

In iOS, when a **UIViewController** presents a popover, its view's ***tintColor*** will change to a b/w color (that way, buttons look non-clickable while the popover is visible). When the popover is dismissed, the color will change back.

There is a subclass of a **UIView** that hold badge count. This views layer's color is supposed to have the same color as the view's ***tintColor***.

How to synchronize the `tintColor` for the sublayer within its superview?

```
// draw orange background layer with border  
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    layer.cornerRadius = rect.height / 2
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 2
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

**Default:**

[image]

**Presented:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `tintColorDidChange` in custom UIView and set `tintColor` to layer's `backgroundColor` in it.

```
override func tintColorDidChange() {
    layer.backgroundColor = tintColor.cgColor
}
```

[image]